# Encoding a twitter response

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, hyperlink, html-encode

I am pulling in my twitter feed with this.

https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php

```
$details = json_decode($result, true);
```

I decode and return the ajax request, however it is returned in text so typically I will get

```
@myname
This is my interesting post #done ✔️  https://shortednedurl @myhandle #help
```

How can I turn the links, hashtags and the twitter usernames into links?

**Edit:**
I tried this

```
val =  encodeURIComponent(myArray[1][0]);
 $('.twitter p').eq(1).html(val);
```

but it just returns an encoded string rather than turning into html.

```
Up%20against%20great%20competition%20
```

Comment: [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: I tried this val =  encodeURIComponent(myArray[1][0]);
 $('.twitter p').eq(1).html(val